# Added certificate to cacerts still "unable to find valid certification path to requested target"

Tags: java, tomcat, ssl-certificate

This may look like a duplicate but it is not.
I added the certificate from the ssl endpoint to my cacerts file. I verified its added. I restarted the jvm and my computer, but I still get unable to find valid certification path to requested target exception.

Comment: Have you a valid certificate? Did you check you are using modified cacerts? Can you log value of state property 'javax.net.ssl.trustStore'?

Comment: I have seen those examples as well, I am not sure how to use it from cmd, I get the following error is not recognized as an internal or external command,operable program or batch file

Comment: To log system property you need jinfo command. This command require process id. You can get process id using command 'jps -v'.

Comment: You probably imported into the wrong cacerts file. If you have a JDK and JRE installed, there are two.

Comment: @EJP I have added my certs to both jdk and jre.

Comment: My answer with help from @lquitadamo worked

Comment: @lquitadamo since this worked locally how do I make it work in prod environment?                                                                                                           
1. Do I have to add the cert to git, if so how?
2. How do I set my system property for trustsore in terms of git? it takes the path that I am not sure about as how it would be in git

Answer (score 0):

In addition to adding the certificate from the ssl endpoint the following helped me fix the issue. I added this system property in my code and it helped me navigate to the required secured endpoint.

```
 System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "path/to/cacerts");
```

However the above one works for local, while doing it for prod deployment I moved the cacerts to my project and change the path to cacerts to the one in my project. This way it worked for both remote and local end points.

Comment: You don't have to define the path to the Java `cacerts` file. Java already knows it. This can only mean you imported to the wrong file.